# Обьясните пожалуйста как почему нет ответа от бота

Tags: python, aiogram

Новичок в библиотеки aiogram
Вопрос такой функция async def check_not_bots(message: types.Message):
Выводит пользователь набор символом и пользователь, должен ввести чтобы бот продолжал работу.Но при правильном вводе выполнятся блок кода else: Нажмите кнопку на  панели, за место - Поздравляю, вы не бот)
код:

```
bot = Bot(token=API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)

generation_capcha = ['Q1dtIvl', 'filRa1', 'quesrt4Q']; randomings = random.choice(generation_capcha)

async def on_startup(_):
    print("Бот начал работу!")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def mains(message: types.Message):
    activasion = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button0 = types.KeyboardButton('Начать работу')
    activasion.add(button0)
    msg = f'Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>'
    await message.reply(msg, reply_markup=activasion, parse_mode='html')

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def check_not_bots(message: types.Message):
    user = message.from_user.id
    if message.text == "Начать работу":
        message_for_user = "<b>Пожалуйста для продолжение работы бота нужно решить капчу.</b>\n\n" \
                           f"Наберите капчу и отправьте её мне:  {randomings}"
        await bot.send_message(user, message_for_user, parse_mode='html')

    else:
        await bot.send_message(user, '<i>Нажмите на кнопку на панели</i>', parse_mode='html')

@dp.message_handler()
async def check_answer(message: types.Message):
    user = message.from_user.id
    if message.text == randomings:
        await bot.send_message(user, '<strong>Поздравляю, вы не бот)</strong>', parse_mode='html')













if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: потому что все сообщения обрабатываются `@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` и в таком виде никогда не дойдет до функции `check_answer`

Comment: А в каком надо обрабатывать?

Comment: ну там сразу и обрабатывай.